# What is the best way of separating ldap connection string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to figure out the best way of getting domain name and the rest of the information into 2 strings by using regex or maybe an exsiting String method available from LDAP string.

Here is the active directory connection string:

```
"LDAP://yourdomain.com/OU=Bla,OU=Bla2,OU=Bla3,DC=yourdomain,DC=com"
```

and the out put I would like to get is:

```
string DomainName = "yourdomain.com"
string Container = "OU=Bla,OU=Bla2,OU=Bla3,DC=yourdomain,DC=com"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a standard URL (with protocol LDAP) and I would use the [appropriate URL parsing/objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_properties.aspx) available to you.

```
var uri = new Uri(LDAPConnectionString);
var host = uri.Host;
var Container = uri.Segments[1];
```

etc.

Comment: I actually didn't think the `URI` class would parse the other end of the path considering it's not *really* a standard URL. However, I tested and `uri.Segments[1]` would give you the second part.

Comment: this seems to be a right way of doing this but I didnt quite get it. Could you give a bit more explanation? So the LDAP string is in the web.config file. I grab it into code and separate it into 2 parts as domainname and the rest. Thanks

Comment: It *is* a URL. You're used to URLs like http://... but the URL spec is protocol-independent

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using simple string manipulation (no need for a Regex).

```
var parts = "LDAP://yourdomain.com/OU=Bla,OU=Bla2,OU=Bla3,DC=yourdomain,DC=com".Replace("LDAP://", "").Split('/');
Console.WriteLine(parts[0]); // yourdomain.com
Console.WriteLine(parts[1]); // OU=Bla,OU=Bla2,OU=Bla3,DC=yourdomain,DC=com
```

Comment: This will fail for the container part if some containername contains a slash. Use `.Split(new Char[] {'/'}, 2)` instead, see [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)